# force update the current branch - how?

Tags: git

I'm on the `my-backup` branch. Now I do `git fetch origin my-backup` and `origin/my-backup` is updated and I see that it was forced pushed. Now I need to updated my local `my-backup` branch to point to `origin/my-backup` branch. I do
`git branch -f my-backup origin/my-backup` but get the warning: `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.` What is the best way to force update current branch to remote without checking out other branch?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `reset`

```
git reset --hard origin/my-backup
```

This will reset your current branch (`my-backup`) with losing all your local changes.

---

`git branch -f my-backup origin/my-backup` is allowed only if your current branch is not `my-backup`.

Comment: Ah classic consistent git.

Comment: But would the changes still be available in the reflog for later `checkout` and `commit`?

Comment: 1) first checkout to main branch. 2) then run git branch -f .... to new commit.. works.

Answer (score 0):

Building on phts's answer here's a slight improvement where you don't need to actually remember what branch you're on:

```
  git reset --hard origin/`git branch --show-current`
```

note that those are back ticks, not single quotes