# Forcibly copying a branch from another branch?

Tags: git

```sh
$ git branch -C pommi  # works fine, creates branch forcibly out of currently checkedout branch.
$ git branch -C pommi master  # gives error, why???
fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.
```

I know that `-C` is for forcibly copying  the branch, when a branch already exists with the same name. How can I create a force copy by explicitly specifying the branch name(which is not checked out) of the source branch to copy?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29559053/2550406) answer your question? TL;DR: you cannot force update the branch you're currently on. check out some other branch first

Comment: Nope, I make a branch(which already exists{want to overwrite that branch) out of current branch. I'm okay with that.
But when I do, 
`git branch -C pommi otherBranch` it says what's the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

Acutually, it was a problem in understanding the syntax for copying, its like

```sh
git branch -C sourceBranch targetBranch
```

So, It's solved, Thanks StackOverflow, and community people.